# How to change a variable value in react on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

When someone clicks on "Add more" button, I want the `pickers` variable to change (contain two instances of `mainPart`.

On page load, there is only one `mainPart` inside `pickers`. But I want to change it when someone clicks on "Add more".

I have a react code like this:

```
export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        // Stuff here
    }
  
    mainPart(a,b,c) {
        return (
            // Stuff here
        )
    }
    
    changeMyVariable(a,b,c,type) {
        if (type==1) {
            return [
                ( 
                    <span>
                        mainPart(a,b,c)
                    </span>
                )
            ]
        }
        if (type==2) {
            return [
                ( 
                    <span>
                        mainPart(a,b,c)
                    </span>
                ),
                ( 
                    <span>
                        mainPart(a,b,c)
                    </span>
                )
            ]
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        let pickers = this.changeMyVariable(a, b, c,1);
        
        return (
            {pickers}
            <button onClick={this.changeMyVariable(a, b, c,2)} type="button">Add more</button>
        );
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly**
You need to use state to make your component render when type changes

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
   this.state = {
     type: 1
  }
}

render(){
    let pickers  =  this.changeMyVariable(a, b,  c,  this.state.type);
   return (<>{pickers}
<button onClick={() => this.setState({type: 2})} /></>
);
}
```

**Secondly**
You didn't handle button click event very well before. Your function would run immediately after render not on button click.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full example using functional component and `useState` and `useEffect` hooks.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
const App = () => {
  const [pickers, setPickers] = useState([]);

  const mainPart = (a, b, c) => {
    return <p>{`${a} ${b} ${c}`}</p>;
  };

  const changeMyVariable = (a, b, c, type) => {
    if (type === 1) {
      setPickers([...pickers, <p>pressed {type}</p>, mainPart(a, b, c)]);
    }
    if (type === 2) {
      setPickers([
        ...pickers,
        <p>pressed {type}</p>,
        mainPart(a, b, c),
        mainPart(a, b, c),
      ]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    changeMyVariable('one default', 'two default', 'three default', 1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {pickers}
      <button
        onClick={() => changeMyVariable('one', 'two', 'three', 1)}
        type="button">
        Add one
      </button>
      <br></br>
      <button
        onClick={() => changeMyVariable('one', 'two', 'three', 2)}
        type="button">
        Add two
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Live Demo of App : [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/tactless-macaroni-and-cheese)

Comment: Hmm, but it is not updating `pickers` variable value

Comment: How can I do that please

Comment: Yup, you have to change state too. That's when rerender triggers and changed value are displayed on the app.

Comment: Wait, let me grab my laptop :)

Comment: I am new to react. How can I do that, please? Thanks a lot. I tried to look for that also, i am running into a infinity loop

Comment: Thanks a lot @ketan

Comment: added full example using hooks and functional components, do check out.
and check out this website: https://fullstackopen.com/ best for ReactJS and its friends

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224745/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-rahul).

Answer (score 1):

also, i would to recommend take a look about useState, other hooks to make it more easer.

```
import React from "react";

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // Stuff here
  }

  mainPart = (a, b, c) => {
    return <h1>Ok1</h1>;
  };

  changeMyVariable = (a, b, c, type) => {
    if (type === 1) {
      return <span>mainPart(a,b,c)</span>;
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <span>mainPart(a,b,c)</span>
          <span>mainPart(a,b,c)</span>
        </>
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    let pickers = this.changeMyVariable(a, b, c, 1);

    return (
      <>
        {pickers}
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            this.changeMyVariable(a, b, c, 2);
          }}
        >
          Add more
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```